# How to "fit in" a cycling bunch?

Tags: etiquette, group-rides

This is a genuine request for ideas on how to be effective in not following the "[Velominati](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/)" rules. How to keep cyclists of all persuasions together and be accepting of others, from leadership to newbies.

**The alternative:**

https://humancyclist.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/the-rules-rewritten-cycling/

**Basically**

> ```
> we ride, we do what we want
>
> I ride, I do what I want
>
> and look how I want
> ```

How can we keep bunch riders together, have regular rides, and not slip into this elitist Velominati (it's not even a word)?

I am after tips, DO's and DONT's on how to keep a smile and not feed into the egos in the bunch. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Find a different group.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - not that easy. A lot of work getting to know people all over again, etc etc etc

Comment: Take up Mountain Biking we hate those rules even more than you.

Comment: This might be more suitable for interpersonal.se

Comment: It's interesting that you mention Audaxes in this context. One of the reasons I've got into that style of riding so much over the last year is the *lack* of snobbery and "the rules" nonsense (though the one about checking your shorts aren't transparent should be taken seriously). This is both on brevets up to 200km and club runs with the local audax club. I'm in the UK, so things might be different here. We tend to ride in a sociably loose bunch rather than on each others wheels, so it may not suit you from that point of view. And the hardcore riders seem just as happy with that as anyone else

Comment: I feel the same. The Rules, except for very few among them, are pompous and stupid. And not funny. The very amount of them — huge! — hints that something is wrong here. A well-functioning system does not need to have that many rules guiding its operation — there should be a few and everything should derive from them.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov +1.. it's that riders take them seriously, yet they themselves fail to adhere to the rules all the time. Especially when it comes to bike gear and parts. That bit I hate because the bike means nothing without the guns and I can outdo 80% of the riders in my group with my fixie let alone a road bike.

Comment: *someone brings up the Velominati Rules and it all goes to s&^&^!* And how many times has this happened?  Does anyone else in the group ever think "it all goes to s&^&^!"?

Comment: Sounds like you need to apply rule #5 ;-)

Comment: The bulk of this "question" appears to be primarily a rant.  Rant removed it's "I hang out with a-holes.  How do I not hang out with a-holes?" and that doesn't seem like a a bicycling question, nor even one that is that interesting or difficult to answer ("You stop.")  Do we need this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it is a rant, not a question.

Comment: Maybe you'd better ask there? http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Speed and Strength are unfortunately the main currency in road groups (i.e., toxic masculinity). If you have it you can guide/control the culture otherwise you’re out of luck. For example if someone constantly criticizes your clothing, next hill climb turn the screws on them. Similarly, if the group conversation gets “snobby”, you can “punish” transgressors by turning the screws where ever appropriate (e.g., climbs, sprints, etc). After breaking their spirit, offer some advice (e.g., “you should try being nicer to the newbie... maybe I will even let you take a sprint”).

Comment: I don't regard demonstrating your physical dominance as very constructive. It seems exactly the behaviour you want to prevent... did you ever ask on interpersonal.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Swifty LOL 2 years later?!

Comment: @Fandango68 "LOL 2 years later?!" yeah, getting on for 2 years, so it's too late to edit my previous comment that wasn't a response to Rider_X exactly, but now it looks that way a little bit because an in-between comment has been deleted. I think it's a good question, keeping groups harmonious and fun is a great ambition for the health of the club or other group.

Comment: Actually looking at it afresh, it reads just fine anyway, I've removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've heard once: if a person offers you a gift and you don't accept it - it remains the property of the other person. And it's the same with criticism. And thus, if you engage yourself into a discussion you most likely end up in a fight over the colour of your bar tape.

Assuming that you are not the only one hating the rules try **not to get into the discussions**. You can use some responses to the comments on your gear (socks, bike, etc.), I've sorted them out from the least offensive:

- if it goes about the socks and such, go "*laundry day, sorry, I'll do my best to match them next time*"
- remarks on how old/outdated your equipment is can be replied with "*gets me going but I'd be glad to try yours if you say it's that great. I know what to upgrade.*"
- general remarks can be replied with "*don't worry, next time I'll go slower so I stay behind you and don't fall into your field of sight*"

Whatever you say, **don't engage into further discussion**. Simply **don't** and stand your ground - you're there for the ride and not for the looks.

This will most likely introduce a split in your group to those who blindly follow Velominati rules and those who, like you, want to enjoy the ride. Only the time will tell if the division remains or dissolves.
Of course some basic rules apply concerning safety and correct gear (road bike).

And worst case scenario is that you become the only outsider. In such case this group wasn't meant for you.

Comment: Awesome tricks, and not just for cycling! "next time I'll go slower…" — truly having a sharp mind and equally sharp tongue feel great!

Answer (score 6):

This is almost a question for https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/.

Any group of people has a spectrum of attitudes and social skills. Just ignore and don't engage with anyone in the group that you don't like, or who acts in a way you find objectionable. Hang out with the people you do like.

Answer (score 5):

Change the riding style. Either go to the mountain biking or touring/endurance riding.

The Rules do not apply to them: to MTB — because it originated from different historical background; to touring — because after two weeks of *uninterrupted cycling* nobody could possibly care how many hair you have and what color your clothes are, because everyone is covered with the same amount of (off)road dirt.

The touring is the most relaxed style in this regard because it is based on survival principles, and whatever allows you (and your group) to achieve the goal, is appropriate.

And if someone even dares to mention The Rules — just dismiss that unwise attempt: "But they are for roadies!"

Comment: Problem is - I AM A ROADIE!

Comment: and I don't have MTB, I don't want one. Although I get the appeal and I may try it one day

Comment: @Fandango68 no, you are not. You are a person who wants to ride a bike. "*You are an X*" is that type of predisposition indoctrinated into people (often by parents or mentors) that is the hardest to get rid of. "I am black so I must do like black people do". "You are a boy so you must not play with girls' dolls". But it is possible to change oneself once you understand that this "I am X" cannot define you, and it does not deny you other options. For example, you can have both MTB and road bikes and ride both of them.

Comment: @Fandango68 In any way, I suggest you trying touring first. It is closer to road biking in technical aspects, although unlike in philosophy. The longer the distance, the less it all matters.

Comment: The "Rules" don't apply to roadies, either.  I don't think I've ever ridden with anyone who **actually** takes them seriously. No one ever really cared about what bike someone was riding (other than "dang, wish I could get a new DuraAce Di2 bike...") or whether or not someone's legs were shaved. Especially not group after group.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's true, but they're a good description of a certain class of roadie and their attitudes. I wouldn't last 5 minutes with them (my road bike is a tourer for starters), and prefer to ride with the sort of people whose reaction to riding a good ride on a heavy bike is "well done" not "you should spend 6 months pay on a bike like mine".

Comment: @Fandango68  I ride a lot of road, but I tend to do it solo.  I'd group-ride perhaps 2 or 3 times a year only.  And those tend to be full-on races.  I love just riding, and keeping up with the loudmouths is fun.   Let your actions speak louder than words.